# How to analyse user survey results

Tags: user-research

I have performed a user research survey on a website and received over 100 results. I now need to analyse these results and report back the findings to the business and the users. Does anyone have any advice on the best approach to analysing this data, things to be looking out for, particular areas to be focusing on etc... All advice is really appreciated.

Comment: Next time you do this try doing a small sample survey so that the full survey is focussed around issues you have already identified. It makes analysis easier as the larger survey is providing more data on the issues you've already identified.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very open ended question. I assume your question is not about statistical analysis.

**Start by Categorizing your answers**

To start I would read through the responses and notice the categories the responses fall into especially those that are relevant to the initial questions you were trying to answer as "findability, choice,  availability, beauty, etc"

After you've compiled categories review the comments and categorize the results.

Some responses will fit into multiple categories.

You then have some "answers" to your question.

Rinse and repeat as your analysis brings up more questions.

Comment: This a quite a common problem - a qualitative survey can produce a lot of very useful information and if you categorise you'll get some basic descriptive statistics ( % doing x versus % doing y etc ). However you will also understand a lot more about your users.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should know what proportion of the population you have sampled. 100 responses for most of my surveys, where there were millions of people in the population, would mean that I likely had not gotten enough data draw any kind of inferences from the numbers. In that case, I would focus on qualitative responses in the analysis. You could also report some summary statistics (such as average, max, min), but be clear that it is only describing who actually took the survey and not the population.

If your population is 100 and you have sampled all of them, then the descriptive statistics could be more helpful and also accurate (obviously).

If you want more details on how to analyze your data, you should provide more detail about the types of questions that were asked.